# How do I set initial CSS values with JavaScript on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to JavaScript, and I'm still trying to learn a lot. I found a snippet that allows for horizontal parallax on scroll. I'm using the following code to set the 'right' css property:

```
var $horizontal = $('.scroll');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

    var position = (scrollPercent * 2500) + ($(document).width() / 2);

    $horizontal.css({
        'right': position
    });
});
```

This works really well once the scroll happens, however, on the load, the 'right' property is, by default, set to 0. It only snaps to my position variable once I start scrolling. How can I call this variable on load and have it modify with scroll?

Comment: Make that code a real function. Call it from the initial load (e.g. DOM ready event) *and* from the scroll.

Comment: The best way to set _initial_ CSS values is to use a stylesheet.

Comment: Teemu - I appreciate that, but the value is a dynamic number based on the document width, so there is no real initial value that I can set in the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the scroll function when the window is finished loading:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...
});

$( window ).load(function() {
   $(window).trigger('scroll');
});
```

Comment: This worked. I'm still trying to understand the math behind it... var s is the number of pixels the user has scrolled (right?). d is how many pixels the total website is if scrolled from top to bottom (right?). What's c? I'm guessing it's the height of the div that the JavaScript is targetting. Is that right?

Comment: Correct except c is the height of the window in this case, basically the visible height of the document.

Comment: Incidentally, the div uses JavaScript to fill up the whole height of the window, so I was TECHNICALLY correct, but for the wrong reasons. Thanks for the help!